# Jquery modal dialog form not appearing as popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to run the code from the following link
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Why doesn't the dialog form appear as a popup?

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample Modal Dialog</title>

<style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<h1>Existing Users:</h1>
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>johndoe1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process.  Embed form markup in the content area, set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var name = $( "#name" ),
        email = $( "#email" ),
        password = $( "#password" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
        tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                if ( bValid ) {
                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The form is displayed but none of the validations work and the popup doesn't appear!

Comment: Please provide browser name and version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see the jquery-ui js/css file anywhere in your code.
You have to include them to make jquery-ui widget work.

Please read
http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i dint know i was supposed to use the download builder to get the code!

Answer (score 1):

You can see this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample Modal Dialog</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog" class="" style="width: auto; min-height: 115px; height: auto; display: none; " scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<h1>Existing Users:</h1>
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>johndoe1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process.  Embed form markup in the content area, set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var name = $( "#name" ),
        email = $( "#email" ),
        password = $( "#password" ),
        allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
        tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                if ( bValid ) {
                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I click create new user I get a popup in chrome with validations working. You might have browser compatibility issues.Which browser you using?

Comment: It works in the website jquery.com, but when i use the code it doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

Always wise to make sure the `$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({` is created inside  `$(function() {`